# smoothly Hidden navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

How can I do it with out resize view frame (or tableView)?
I use this code and I have resized view then I scroll down/up
I use code, not storyboard

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 {
if ([gestureRecognizer class] == [UIPanGestureRecognizer class])
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRec = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
    CGPoint distance = [panGestureRec translationInView:self.tableView];

    if (distance.y > 0 || distance.y < 0)
    {
        if (distance.y > 0) // down
        {
            //NSLog(@"user swiped down");
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

        } else if (distance.y < 0) //up
        {
            //NSLog(@"user swiped up");
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        }

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code . This will give smooth animation (Used UIView Animation property)**

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 {
if ([gestureRecognizer class] == [UIPanGestureRecognizer class])
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRec = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
    CGPoint distance = [panGestureRec translationInView:self.tableView];

    if (distance.y > 0 || distance.y < 0)
    {
        if (distance.y > 0) // down
        {
            //NSLog(@"user swiped down");
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

        } else if (distance.y < 0) //up
        {
            //NSLog(@"user swiped up");
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        }

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }

   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
return YES;
```

Comment: Put UIView animation code inside if condition (if (distance.y > 0 || distance.y < 0)). I think it will work out